# Connect to my localhost from another computer NOT in the same network

Tags: http, localhost

I have a real IP. Or so I think, basically how I tested this is under windows in `cmd` I pinged my IP address and I got packages back, so that must mean it's real. However when I start my `xampp` and go to my IP address in the browser I get

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server

I tried looking up other questions but they didn't help cause all answers I found were suggesting LAN connection. Can you please explain to me any extra steps I need to take or link an answer that does that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to start your xampp with `apache_start.bat`? it would return much more errors if something went wrong.

Comment: @demonking Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that, nothing is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access your localhost from other computers is over a Local Area Network (LAN); whether wired or wireless, there has to be a physical connection between the computers.

Once the computers are connected, you can access your localhost from the browser with the name of the computer on other computers:

http ://your-computer/path/to/files/

It also works on the same computer, so you can test it there.

You can find the name of your computer by going to the "Network" section in Windows Explorer.

EDIT:

If you want to access a localhost from a computer that is on another network, you have to create a web server; more or less what you would be paying for from a hosting company. Here is how you would do it:

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/

Comment: But what if they aren't in the same network. It makes sense I guess I only have to allow the connection somehow :/

Comment: If they aren't on the same network, the entire computer has to be setup as a server and your network must have a static IP address (provided by your ISP) and be setup to accept incoming connections (most home networks are not)

Comment: You could look for `apache listen`.if you have access to the router, you could make a portforward to the choosen port. And then someone could access your computer with `routerIP:yourChoosenPort`. But be aware, that you have a static ip address. Otherwise search for dyndns or something similiar

Comment: @demonking I have access to the router, just exactly what do I need to do, you say? `:D` My IP is static, hasn't changed in years.

Comment: For reliable access, it would still require that you acquire a static IP address from your ISP (usually have to pay for it), because under normal circumstances, your automatically assigned IP address changes at minimum multiple times throughout the day, in some cases on every request.

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz my ISP gives me the option to change between a static IP and a dynamic IP for free. Are they the coolest or what? `:D` And it's as easy as click-click-done

Comment: I would have to say they are, because when I set up a web server, I had to pay a monthly fee to get a static IP.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Then it would be much easier, google for `apache listen` so you could specify each port you want. Then you have to look, how you could create a port forwarding on your router.The portforward
should be similiar with the port used with `listen`. When you have finished it , then you could access your computer with `rounterIP:PORT`.

Comment: @demonking what difference does the port make? What's wrong with 80? Basically what you're saying is that port forwarding is going to make the magic happen? I'm going to look for this now.

Comment: The problem with port 80 would be, if another application would listen on port 80 too. Some example Skype and Apache, i don't know how it's now, but earlier they block each other. Here some old post http://blog.techsoftsolutions.net/?p=315

Comment: @demonking Well if that were the case then local requests wouldn't work as well, but they do, fortunately. What I found after googling is that I have to add my real IP to the listen list, but I'm still trying to figure out how